# Is it possible to feed the output back to input in artificial neural network?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, linear-regression, loss-function

I am currently designing a artificial neural network for a problem with a decay curve.
For example, building a model for predicting the durability of the some material. It may includes the environment condition like temperature and humidity.

However, it is not adequate to predict the durability of the material. For such a problem, I think it is better to using the output durability of previous time slots as one of the current input to predict the durability of next time slot.

Moreover, I do not know how to train a model which feed the output back to input as one of the input columns has only the initial value before training.

For this case,

**Method 1 (fail)**
I have tried to fill the predicted output durability of current row to the input durability of next row. Nevertheless, it will prevent the model from "loss.backward()" so we cannot compute and update the gradient if we do so. The gradient function used was "CopySlices" instead of "MSELoss" when I copied the predicted output to the next row of the input data.

[Feed output to input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2a3A.png)

[gradient function -copy-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDlWB.png)

**Method 2 "fill the input column with expected output"**
In this method, I fill the blank input column with expected output (row-1) before training the model. Filling the input column with expected output of previous row is only done for training. For real prediction, I will feed the predicted output to the input. In this case, I am successful to train a overfitting model with MSELoss.

Moreover, I do not believe it is a right method as it uses the expected output as the input no matter how bad it predict. I strongly believed that it is not a right method.

---

Therefore, I want to ask whether it is possible to feed output to input in linear regression problem using artificial neural network.

I apologize for uploading no code here as I am not convenient to upload the full code here. It may be confidential.

Comment: Sorry, it is not a linear regression problem. It is a non-linear curve like theta decay curve.

Comment: What is the data you want to feed into the NN? If I understand it correctly, your data only consists of an initial value and a final value? Or do you also have a sequence of steps?

Comment: No, there is only the initial value of stiffness(t-1). There are 4 inputs, Stiffness(t-1), temperature, humidity and accumulated loading.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need an RNN (recurrent neural network). This tutorial is pretty helpful for understanding an RNN: https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/.

Comment: Does it mean RNN do the feedback for me in the hidden layer and I do not need to feed the input to output manually?

Comment: @MissingSomeHead yes. An RNN does h(t) = W_h * h(t-1) + W_x * x(t) whereas a normal Feedforward Layer only does h(t) = W_x * x(t).

Comment: RNN seems to use feedback to repeat the pattern. However, I am not going to repeat the pattern. I want to decay the output. It must drop deeper than the previous drop value.